# Does cloud-init service in OpenStack VM fetches UserData on every instance reboot

Tags: openstack-nova, cloud-init

I would like to understand how does cloud-init service in OpenStack VM fetches the UserData content on every reboot ? I believe it fetches through OpenStack Metadata server but **does this happen on every instance reboot** ?

Because I see the below list of files which has UserData content are re-generated every time on reboot

```
./instances/61df18f8-ff4b-4e27-afb2-e2e8aaffde1d/scripts/part-001
./instances/61df18f8-ff4b-4e27-afb2-e2e8aaffde1d/user-data.txt
./instances/61df18f8-ff4b-4e27-afb2-e2e8aaffde1d/user-data.txt.i
./instances/61df18f8-ff4b-4e27-afb2-e2e8aaffde1d/obj.pkl
```

**Note:** OpenStack VM is created through Nova API.